# SendEmail using Sendgrid - SendEmailAsync

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

I have code that was working until I ungraded Framework from 4.5 to 4.7. Now it doesn't work any more. Are there any suggestion how I can make it work.
There is no error but

```
response:
Id = 207, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"   System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SendGrid.Response>
```

```
public static void SendMail(EmailBuilder email)
{
   try
    {

        /* CREDENTIALS
         * ===================================================*/
        string sgUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUserName"];
        string sgPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPassword"];


        /* CREATE THE MAIL MESSAGE
         * ===================================================*/
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        
        var plainTextContent ="" ;
        if (email.Style == 2)
            plainTextContent = email.Body;
        if (email.Style == 1)
            plainTextContent = email.Body;

        var apiKey = sgPassword;
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromAddress"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromName"]);
        var subject = email.EmailSubject;
        var to = new EmailAddress(email.EmailAddress, email.FirstName + " " + email.LastName);
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, plainTextContent);
        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    }
}

I tried to change that to `public async Task SendMail` but then I have difficulties in calling that from another class.
For this one it was `Mailer.SendMail(email)`
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

Answer (score 3):

As you are calling an async method, if you don't want to change the return type to Task, you can use the following approach.

```
client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
      .GetAwaiter()
      .GetResult();
```

Anyway, I'd recommend that you use the `await` word and do all the necessary refactorings to make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

Are 3 possibilities -

1)

```
At first make it async. From some version it was problem. So begin will be as

public async Task testEmail()
{  ...
var result = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

2. If it will not work check where you are sending mail. E.g. to Yahoo etc. it could not work.
3. Are you with this project at some corporate? Tough cyber security rules can block it ... aaand you are done until you ask for exclude from the "forbidden list".